# Building With Maven

Tags: maven

Hello I've been trying to create a proper Maven build for a bit now. I created my Pom.xml file which is this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>XO Artifactory</name>
  <url>artifactory:8081/artifactory/webapp/home.html?0</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

I'm trying to have the build publish to artifactory, I'm also trying to have the builds dependency be artifactory as well. For the build to publish to artifactory it would be something I set up in the settings.xml correct?

Settings.xml:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>artifactory:8081/artifactory/webapp/home.html?0</id>
      <username>mhopper</username>
      <password>*******</password>
    </server>
  </servers>

</settings>
```

Comment: Are you are running any maven commands already to try to accomplish this? If so, can you share them?

Comment: Right now I'm using "mvn package"

Comment: You will want to look into the deploy phase - https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two steps for this:

1. Add a proper server setting to your local ~/.m2/settings.xml containing an id of your server and the credentials to access it:

   ```xml
   <servers>
     <server>
       <id>deployment</id>
       <username>deployment</username>
       <password>deployment123</password>
     </server>
   </servers>
   ```
2. Backref the id in your projects pom.xml where you define the actual url for this:

   ```xml
   <distributionManagement>
     <repository>
       <id>deployment</id>
       <name>Internal Releases</name>
       <url>artifactory:8081/artifactory/releases</url>
     </repository>
     <snapshotRepository>
       <id>deployment</id>
       <name>Internal Snapshots</name>
       <url>artifactory:8081/artifactory/snapshots</url>
     </snapshotRepository>
   </distributionManagement>
   ```

Comment: I have a Settings.xml file I'll add it in my initial description! I'll edit my Pom.xml too and see if that works!

Comment: In your settings.xml there should be an id not the complete url of the artifact repository.